# gcc linker script - bin file generated is ... almost 400MB, the device has 512KB FLASH

Tags: linker, stm32, binutils

I have done something silly probably but can't find the error:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x10004000;    /* end of CCMRAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x100;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x1000; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */

_configLength = 2K;

MEMORY 
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 16K
CONFIG (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x8000000 + 512K - _configLength, LENGTH = _configLength
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000 + 32K, LENGTH = 512K - _configLength - 32K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .sizedata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.sizedata))
    KEEP(*(.sizedata*)) 
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH



  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

   _ROMEND = .;

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH

  _ROMSIZE = _ROMEND + SIZEOF(.data) - ORIGIN(FLASH);


  _siconfig = LOADADDR(.configsection);

  .configsection :
  {     
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sconfig = .;       
    /*KEEP(*(.configsection))
    (.configsection*)*/
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _econfig = _sconfig + _configLength;   
  } > CONFIG


  _sisram = LOADADDR(.sram);

  /* CCM-RAM section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section,
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .sram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ssram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram start */
    *(.ram)
    *(.ram*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _esram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram end */
  } >RAM



  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >CCMRAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >CCMRAM 



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
    *(.configsection) 
    *(.configsection*) 
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

If you kindly could take a look :) The elf file is OK. I can program & debug program.

Comment: Big mess in your linker script... but OK, seems that RAM or part of RAM section is copying into binary, generate hex file and look which addresses are there and compare it with map file. What do you have in `.ram` sections?

Comment: @vlk - yes mess. Actually I wrote the new one and all is OK. So I have sorted it out. As you see I was just adding, removing etc etc during the development without cleaning. But as often it is easier to write the new one than find the error.

Comment: As suggested by @vlk, do a `arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex firmware.elf firmware.bin` instead of `binary` and open the resulting `.hex` file in any program that understands Intel Hex. That should give you an idea of what data is unnecessary or placed incorrectly.

Comment: I have another problem but I will ask another question